# Why is the move keyword not always needed even when the closure takes ownership of a value?

Tags: rust

While reading the last chapter of the Rust book, I couldn't help but notice that `move` was not used within a closure:

```
fn main() {
    let listener = TcpListener::bind("127.0.0.1:7878").unwrap();

    for stream in listener.incoming() {
        let stream = stream.unwrap();

        // move not used here
        thread::spawn(|| {
            handle_connection(stream);
        });
    }
}
```

Here is the function signature of `handle_connection`:

```
fn handle_connection(mut stream: TcpStream) {}
```

Why isn't `move` used here? What would cause `move` to be required from within the closure?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Rust can tell when a closure uses a value from the environment in a way that requires a move**. Like calling a function that takes the argument by value (your `handle_connection` case):

```
let s = String::from("hi");
let c = || drop(s);  // <-- `drop()` takes its argument by value
                     //      Thus, the compiler knows `c` is a move closure
```

Or if the closure returns the object by value:

```
let s = String::from("hi");
let c = || s;  // <-- `s` is returned (FnOnce() -> String)
               //      Thus, the compiler knows `c` is a move closure
```

So usually, you don't have to annotate the `move` keyword to explicitly tell the compiler.

*However*, **if the closure uses the value from the environment only via references, the compiler assumes that moving that variable into the closure is not necessary**. But it might still be necessary for another reason: lifetimes. Example:

```
fn get_printer(s: String) -> Box<Fn()> {
    Box::new(|| println!("{}", s))
}
```

In this case, the compiler only sees that `s` is used in read only fashion via reference (`println` doesn't consume its arguments). Thus the compiler doesn't make the closure a move closure. But this results in a lifetime error, because `s` now lives in the stackframe of `get_printer` and the closure outlives that stackframe. So in this case, you have to force the compiler to move the environment into the closure by adding `move`:

```
fn get_printer(s: String) -> Box<Fn()> {
    Box::new(move || println!("{}", s))
}
```